# Solution for show multi-points(Latitude, Longitude) in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new in Android developing and location base applications in Google.
By tutorial of Google, i could show a single location.
After that i develop it more and read Double Latitude and Double Longitude from my DB.( By select with a where as you will see ! )
Now, i want to show all points(Latitude and Longitude)that exist in my DB.
I can read them from DB, but how can i show multi points(Latitude and Longitude) in my app.
Here is my code of MainActivity named LocationService :

```
    public class LocationService extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_service);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
        Statement statement;

        try {
            statement = connectionHelper.getMyConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select Latitude, Longitude from myDB where Name='name'");
            if(resultSet.next()) {
                do {
                    latitude = Double.valueOf(resultSet.getString("Latitude"));
                    longitude = Double.valueOf(resultSet.getString("Longitude"));
                    LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("Marker in Place!"));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));

                } while (resultSet.next());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//

    }
}
```

In onMapReady method i show a single point that is selected in my statement.
Now i want to get all points without where clause.(All Latitude and Longitude) and show them all.
I am looking for the best solution.
I will appreciate any help.
Best Regards !

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create `ArrayList<LatLag>` and add one by one in that

```
   List<LatLag> _list=new ArrayList<LatLng>();

   if(resultSet.next()) {
            do {
                latitude = Double.valueOf(resultSet.getString("Latitude"));
                longitude = Double.valueOf(resultSet.getString("Longitude"));
                LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

               _list.add(myLocation );
            } while (resultSet.next());
        }
```

At last you got all the points in `_list`

Answer (score 0):

Create a MapPoint class

```
public class MapPoint{
     String name;
     double long;
     double lat;
     public MapPoint(String name, double long, double lat){
           this.name = name;
           this.long = long;
           this.lat = lat;
     }
```

Then read your points from database to `List<MapPoint> mList` and do this in onMapReady

```
MapPoint[] mPoint;
mPoint = mList.toArray(new MapPoint[]{});
for (int i = 0; i < mPoint.length(); i++) {

        double latitude = mPoint[i].lat();
        double longitude = mPoint[i].long();

        marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(mPoint[i].name());
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
```

Hope it's help.